# When to use OCI_B_INT in PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, integer, oracle-call-interface

I have an Oracle table with this structure:

```
column             type           key
---------------------------------------------
id                 integer        primary key
user_id            integer        foreign key
colony_id          number(14)     foreign key
last_upd_username  varchar2(50)
last_upd_date      date
```

I didn't create the table but I think `colony_id` should be an `integer` as well - not `number` *(too late now to change it anyways)*.

I have a query that inserts multiple rows in this table:

```php
$colonies = array_map("intval", $post['colonies']);

# Assign colonies to $user_id
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_colonies (
    id,
    user_id,
    colony_id,
    last_upd_username,
    last_upd_date
  ) VALUES (
    user_colonies_seq.NEXTVAL,
    :user_id,
    :colony_id,
    :username,
    sysdate
  )";

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":user_id", $user_id);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":colony_id", $colony);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":username", $username);

foreach($colonies as $colony) {
  $r = oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
  if(!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($stmt);
    $result['err'][] = $e['message'];
  }
}

$result['msg'] = 'success';

oci_commit($conn);
oci_free_statement($stmt);

echo json_encode($result);
```

This kind of work because the query runs fine (`$e['message']`) is always `null`. However when I look at the inserted rows, the `colony_id` do not make any sense, they're just a bunch of random integers from 1 to 9 whereas I'm expecting actual IDs (should be in the thousands).

I was able to make it work by changing

```php
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":colony_id", $colony);
```

into

```php
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":colony_id", $colony, -1, OCI_B_INT);
```

By using [`OCI_B_INT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php), the correct IDs are used and everything works fine. I do not understand when and how to use that flag though because binding `$user_id` to `":user_id"` worked fine without the flag. The only difference I could see is the data type (`integer` vs `number(14)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really isn't a problem with the `OCI_B_INT` flag. The real culprit here is the `maxlength` parameter.

> You **must** specify `maxlength` when using an OUT bind so that PHP
>   allocates enough memory to hold the returned value.
>
> For IN binds it is recommended to set the `maxlength` length if the
>   statement is re-executed multiple times with different values for the
>   PHP variable. Otherwise Oracle may truncate data to the length of the
>   initial PHP variable value. If you don't know what the maximum length
>   will be, then re-call `oci_bind_by_name()` with the current data size
>   prior to each `oci_execute()` call. Binding an unnecessarily large
>   length will have an impact on process memory in the database.

```php
foreach($colonies as $colony) {
  oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":colony_id", $colony, -1, OCI_B_INT);
  $r = oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
}
```